# Unable to load tag handler class "null" for tag "ui:composition"

Tags: eclipse, jboss, facelets, myfaces, trinidad

I am trying to create a JSF application using MyFaces and Trinidad. I have added the following JARs to my `/WEB-INF/lib`:

- commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
- commons-collections-3.1.jar
- commons-digester-1.6.jar
- commons-el-1.0.jar
- commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
- el-ri.jar
- jsf-facelets-1.1.14.jar
- jstl-1.1.0.jar
- trinidad-api-1.0.13.jar
- trinidad-impl-1.0.13.jar
- myfaces-api-1.1.9.jar
- myfaces-impl-1.1.9.jar

The `facelets.tld` file is included in `/WEB-INF` folder.

I am tryng to run this in Eclipse Helios with JBoss 4.2 and JDK 1.5. The server starts fine and I could see in the logs that all `faces-config.xml` files were read by MyFaces and that it starts up without any errors.

However, when I open a JSPX page, then it gives the following exception:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to load tag handler class "null" for tag "ui:composition"
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:51)
```

Here's the markup of the JSPX page:

```
<jsp:root version="2.0" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"
    xmlns:i="http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt"
    xmlns:tr="http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad"
    xmlns:trh="http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/html"
    xmlns:t="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk">
    <ui:composition>
        <ui:define name="MyPage">
            <tr:form id="MyForm">
                <trh:tableLayout width= "80%">
                    <trh:rowLayout>
                        <trh:cellFormat>
                            <tr:outputText id="output" value="Sucess"></tr:outputText>
                        </trh:cellFormat>
                    </trh:rowLayout>
                </trh:tableLayout>
            </tr:form>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</jsp:root>
```

The same code works fine in WAS 6.1. I tried it with Tomcat 6 as well, it gave exactly the same problem.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Did you follow this guide? http://wiki.apache.org/myfaces/Facelets_with_Trinidad

Comment: @JasperdeVries Yes i do followed the guide 
I am trying to use JSP with Facelets  
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.ALTERNATE_VIEW_HANDLER - com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler  
facelets.VIEW_MAPPINGS -*.jspx  
facelets.SKIP_COMMENTS - true  
facelets.BUFFER_SIZE - 16384  
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.CHANGE_PERSISTENCE - session

Comment: In faces-Config.xml
<default-render-kit-id>
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.core
</default-render-kit-id>

Facelets entry is not added in faces-config.xml
<application>
    <view-handler>
      com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler
    </view-handler>    
  </application>